# How to make multiple custom taxonomies sit under custom post type slug?

Tags: php, custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type called `resources` which has been registered as so:

```
register_post_type(
  'Resources',
  theme_build_post_args(
    // $slug, $singular, $plural
    'resources', 'Resource', 'Resources',
    array(
      'menu_position' => 20,
       'has_archive'    => true,
      //'has_archive'   => 'types',
      'public'          => true,
      'supports'            => array('title', 'revisions', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'author'),
      'taxonomies'      => array('topics', 'types', 'industries'),
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'resources/%types%')
    )
  )
);
```

This post type has three taxonomies which have been registered like this:

```
register_taxonomy(
  'topics',
  'topics',
  array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'label' => 'Topics',
    'query_var' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    // 'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'resources')
  )
);

register_taxonomy(
  'types',
  'types',
  array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'label' => 'Types',
    'query_var' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    // 'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'resources')
  )
);

register_taxonomy(
  'industries',
  'industries',
  array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'label' => 'Industry',
    'query_var' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    // 'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'resources')
  )
);
```

Currently, when accessing a category defined in any taxonomy, the slug ignores `/resources`. For example, I have a `type` called `Article`. When accessing this page, it sits on `/types/article/` when I need it to sit on `/resources/types/article/`.

The same applies for `topics` and `industries`.

Now I have seen approaches stating this should do the trick:

`'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'resources/%types%')`

However, the above doesn't work for `types`, meaning types still do not sit under `/resources`, but also, I need this to occur for 3 taxonomies, rather than just 1 and I cannot `rewrite` slugs for 3 taxonomies.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Your question was not clear to me. "*I need it to sit on /resources/types/article/*" - are you trying to customize the permalink of the *posts* in your `resources` CPT, or is it the permalink of the *terms* in your taxonomy? (clicking on a term permalink would bring you to the term's archive which by default displays posts in that term) And for example the `types` taxonomy, do you want its terms to have the structure `/resources/types/<term slug>` (e.g. `/resources/types/type-one`), or do you want it be `/resources/<term slug>` (e.g. `/resources/type-one`) instead? I.e. No `/types` there.

Comment: @SallyCJ - The structure I'm after is `/resources/types/<term slug>`. For example, If I have a `type` called "Article", the structure I'm after is `/resources/types/article`. If I have an `industry` called "Accounting" the structure I'm after is `/resources/industries/accounting`. Lastly, if I have a `topic` called "Security", then the structure I'm after is `/resources/topics/security`

Comment: In that case, you just need to use `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'resources/<taxonomy>')`, e.g. `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'resources/topics')` for the `topics` taxonomy. Have you already tried that?

Comment: @SallyCJ - That's correct, I've already tried that for a single taxonomy, but the slug still remains as `/topics/accounting/`. Also, as mentioned above, I need this implemented for three different taxonomies, not just for one. As far as I can see `rewrite` is only possible for one taxonomy?

Comment: Before I answer that, can you show the permalink structure you want for the posts in your `resources` CPT? Because in the question, I see it's set to `resources/%types%`? What would replace `%types%`? Or did you use that structure just because you were trying to get your taxonomies sit under `/resources`?

Comment: @SallyCJ - My permalink structure is just `/%postname%/`. I was testing `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'resources/%types%')` just to see if that would make `types` sit under `/resources` and if it was successful, was going to explore how to apply the same for the other 2 taxonomies. However, it didn't achieve what I was after. But, left the code in the demo to showcase what I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You commented, "*As far as I can see `rewrite` is only possible for one taxonomy?*".

So no, that's not true, it's possible for every taxonomy. Just remember that each taxonomy should have a unique rewrite slug, so that it does not conflict with other permalinks (for other taxonomies and for post types like `post`, `page`, etc.). So for instance, if the `topics` taxonomy uses `topics` as the rewrite slug, then your `types` and `industries` taxonomies need to *use a different rewrite slug*. (If you really must use/share the same slug, it's not impossible, but it's not in scope of this answer)

Now if these are the permalink structures that you want:

- `/resources/topics/<term slug>` for the `topics` taxonomy
- `/resources/types/<term slug>` for the `types` taxonomy
- `/resources/industries/<term slug>` for the `industries` taxonomy

where an example permalink (URL) would look like this:

- `https://example.com/resources/topics/security/` for a term with the slug `security`, in the `topics` taxonomy
- `https://example.com/resources/types/article/` for a term with the slug `article`, in the `types` taxonomy
- `https://example.com/resources/industries/accounting/` for a term with the slug `accounting`, in the `industries` taxonomy

Then just set the rewrite slug for your taxonomy to `resources/<taxonomy>`, like so:

(this is the actual code I tried & tested working with WordPress v6.1.1)

```php
function my_register_post_types() {
    register_post_type(
        'resources', // post type name/slug
        array(
            'public'  => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'resources' ),
            'labels'  => array(
                'name' => 'Resources',
                // other labels
            ),
            // other args
        )
    );
}

function my_register_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'topics',    // taxonomy name/slug
        'resources', // attach to this post type
        array(
            'public'       => true,
            'rewrite'      => array( 'slug' => 'resources/topics' ),
            'label'        => 'Topics',
            'hierarchical' => true,
            // other args
        )
    );

    register_taxonomy(
        'types',     // taxonomy name/slug
        'resources', // attach to this post type
        array(
            'public'       => true,
            'rewrite'      => array( 'slug' => 'resources/types' ),
            'label'        => 'Types',
            'hierarchical' => true,
            // other args
        )
    );

    register_taxonomy(
        'industries', // taxonomy name/slug
        'resources',  // attach to this post type
        array(
            'public'       => true,
            'rewrite'      => array( 'slug' => 'resources/industries' ),
            'label'        => 'Industries',
            'hierarchical' => true,
            // other args
        )
    );
}
```

However, you need to first register the taxonomies, and only after that, register your `resources` post type, *if its rewrite slug is `resources`, which is the default value, or that the slug starts with `resources/`*. Otherwise, your term permalinks would result in a 404 error page. :/

```php
// Register the taxonomy first.
add_action( 'init', 'my_register_taxonomies' );

// Then the post type.
add_action( 'init', 'my_register_post_types' );
```

Also, be sure to flush the rewrite rules (i.e. re-save your permalinks), by simply visiting the Permalink Settings admin page.

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive breakdown, wasn't aware you could attach taxonomies to post types this way. Can confirm your solution worked for me. Many thanks again! :)

Comment: Glad it worked for you, and you might want to set [`with_front`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/#arguments) to `false`, in case the permalink structure (the one you set via the "Permalink structure" field on the Permalink Settings page) for the `post` type would have a "front", i.e. a prefix like `blog/` as in `/blog/%postname%/`. Because by default, that "front" will be added to taxonomy and CPT permalinks, unless `with_front` is explicitly set to `false`.

Comment: Additionally, note that the 1st parameter for `register_post_type()` is a post type name/*slug*, so always use a slug and not the post type's label - I see you use the uppercase `R` as in `Resources`, so that should instead be `resources`, just like in my example 

Comment: Sally CJ thanks so much for explaining the order of registration of custom type posts and taxonomies, save me, really, save me.